# magento database import syntax error

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, magento

I'm working with Magento, Created a complete site and trying go live. I exported database from local server and trying import into live server. unfortunately, I am getting this error.

**Error**

[image]

Comment: You're trying to run HTML as  SQL query?

Comment: the actual query isn't being send, you're sending `<html>` code which will not work as a query

Answer (score 0):

```
* { display: none;
```

The ; symbol delineates the end of a SQL query. Obviously, in this case if that's the end of the query the server does not know what to do, hence the error.

You need to specify a new delimiter (I often use |) so that phpMyAdmin knows when the script is complete.